# Каким образом компании зарабатывают на opensource?

Tags: лицензирование, opensource, it-бизнес

Меня всегда интересовал вопрос, каким образом компании зарабатывают на opensource проектах? У меня существует две догадки (к сожалению я в вопросах лицензирования не силен).

1. Должна существовать лицензия, которая позволяет распространять коммерческое по на базе открытого (например без предоставления исходного кода по требованию). Тогда вполне логично, что на этом можно заработать.
2. Можно продавать услуги по обслуживанию открытого по, но тогда непонятно, кто будет готов заплатить за услуги подобного рода? (хотя тут как по мне можно привести пример обслуживания серверов, использующих открытое по)

Comment: Пример - [Red Hat](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat), которые разрабатывают дистрибутив [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux), который, с одной стороны, распространяется под лицензией GNU GPL, с другой стороны - Rad Hat оказывают по нему платную техподдержку, бинарные пакеты обновлений платные (при том что их исходники открыты). Вот такое вот совмещение "несовместимого".

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть фильм Revolution OS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSt1vNqIfFw
Думаю, он ответит на многие ваши вопросы о мире OpenSource и даже на те, которые еще не появились.
Фильм очень захватывающий и вы не пожалеете потраченного времени.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1F_MfLRlX0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Варианты:

- ПО с откодом может быть разделено на **базовый** функционал и на **дополнительный** (модули, пакеты и прочее). Дополнительные делают платным, а базовый так и остаётся бесплатным, но ограниченным в возможностях, и для того чтобы эти возможности расширить, клиенты покупают доп. возможности.
- Если, как сказано в вопросе, продукт хотят распространять без предоставления кода, то можно купить такую расширенную лицензию у разработчиков откод проекта.
- Платное консультированию и внедрение ПО.
- Написание и продажа учебных пособий для ПО.
- Реклама в основном ПО, куда же без неё.
- Написание (создание) обучающих уроков или каких-либо других ресурсов (сайтов, видео и т.п), где также можно встретить рекламу.
- Спонсирование, бывает и такое.
- Разновидность ПО: открытое-бесплатное и корпоративное.
- Продажа атрибутики (логотипов, символов): наклейки, игрушки и т.п.