# Для чего нужен репозиторий исходного кода?

Tags: github, лицензирование, репозиторий

Существует множество репозиториев исходного кода, самый известный из которых GitHub (но это не точно).

Понятно что это даёт некоторые удобства, но, выкладывая исходный код, разработчик понимает, что его авторские права в этот момент очень формальны. Ведь любой может взять этот код, изменить как ему угодно и использовать в своих проектах, не смотря на лицензию под которой этот код публиковали.

Так ли высоко преимущество от размещения исходного кода в открытом репозитории перед очевидными рисками? И как разработчики относятся к вопросу неправомерного использования их кода?

Comment: Github - это не репозиторий. Ознакомьтесь с `Фондом свободного программного обеспечения` и `Открытым программным обеспечением`. Важно понимать философию открытого ПО, зачем это делают другие программисты, такие как Ричард Столлман, Торвальдс, Кен Томпсон, Деннис Ритчи и другие умы.
Информацию о лицензии можно прочитать в сети.

Comment: @matz Ричард Столлман как раз таки противник opensource

Comment: @Denis разве, где вы это прочитали?  Его ПО тоже есть в исходниках.

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр нет возможности сейчас доказать вам то, что не принципиально относительно вопроса

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667332 смежные цели данного подхода.

Comment: @Denis хм. т.е. основатель движения свободного ПО, автор нескольких достаточно популярных до сих пор  программ с открытым исходным кодом является противником OpenSource. И,как минимум один из авторов лицензии GNU GPL.

Я согласен, что это не относится к вопросу. Но все же как-то странно   все это....

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр freesoftware и opensource значительно отличающиеся понятия. Но да, это к вопросу не относится.

Comment: @Denis а при чем здесь FreeSoftware? Повторюсь Столман не противник ни того не другого. Но именно он выделил OpenSource и продвигает именно его. Т.к. FreeSoftware не обязательно свободное и не укладывается в его идеи в полном объеме. Противником OpenSource он по определению не является.

Comment: Напрашивается простой вопрос: НУ И ЧТО!? Большинство пользователей github/bitbucket/etc просто не волнует проблема "угона" кода. А некоторые и вообще были бы рады, если бы их код был бы кому-то полезен. Те, кто энтерпрайз, но хотят прелестей из мира опенсора в приватном порядке, поднимают свои "репозитории" кода или используют закрытые, но на публичных сервисах, в конце-концов.

Comment: Кстати говоря ПО с открытым исходным кодом не обязательно бесплатное. Т.к. по той же лицензии GNU GPL я исходники обязан только пользователю предоставить. И такое случается, на некоторых проектах пользователь не будет спешить раскидывать исходники на право и налево.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: «[Авторские права на GitHub?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768602/208074)».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В публичных репозиториях на github и подобных сервисах размещают проекты с открытым исходным кодом, т.е. автор уже принял решение.  Плюсы от такого размещения: возможность получать от сторонних людей правки и доработки - на это не всегда у самого хватает время. Кроме того, мне например, помогали с локализацией ПО на другие языки.

Самый яркий пример ядро linux, а так же море ПО GNU. Развиваются бывает их форкают и со временем форк вытесняет оригинал. Это нормально. Людям нужен хороший инструмент. И если у меня нет времени развивать, что плохого если этим займется кто-то еще - я же и буду пользоваться.  GNU и Linux уже сколько лет развиваются.

Да бывали случаи и нарушали открытые лицензии (на сколько я помню у GIMP был закрытый клон. Но кому он нужен? Да и, при желании, можно и в суд подать.